# C# Windows Forms and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to know if it is possible to combine XAML with Window Form or reverse. Also I would like to know a good place to learn how to work with both of them.

For example I want to make a XAML window on which I want to add a button with an event action wrote in C#.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Yes you can, there is nothing special about the example you cited, and there's no better teacher than experience, so get some express edition of Visual Studio and start coding.

Comment: Could you clarify your questiona bit, please? Do you 1) want to use a WPF GUI defined in XAML (e.g. a WPF user control) in a WinForms window (or the other way round), or do you 2) want to use XAML to define a WinForms-only GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible (both ways)

[WinForms in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx)

[WPF in WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx)

In both cases you add a special control that acts as a host for the other environment.

Answer (score 0):

[WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) allows you to host a Windows Forms control on a WPF page.